# kvm error in syslog says cpu0 unhandled rdmsr

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, syslog

I have a server that hosts about 20 KVM guest machines.  It's syslog is, at times, flooded with messages like these:

> 00:17:36 vhost-server kernel: [  157.835078] kvm: 3138: cpu0 unhandled
>   rdmsr: 0xc0010112 Mar 28 00:17:36 vhost-server kernel: [  157.835108]
>   kvm: 3138: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010048 Mar 28 00:17:36
>   vhost-server kernel: [  157.999164] kvm: 3138: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr:
>   0xc0010001 Mar 28 00:17:37 vhost-server kernel: [  158.378247] kvm:
>   3179: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010112 Mar 28 00:17:37 vhost-server
>   kernel: [  158.378277] kvm: 3179: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010048 Mar
>   28 00:17:37 vhost-server kernel: [  158.551881] kvm: 3179: cpu0
>   unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010001 Mar 28 00:17:39 vhost-server kernel: [ 
>   160.474937] kvm: 3508: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010112 Mar 28 00:17:43 vhost-server kernel: [  164.335746] kvm: 3342: cpu0 unhandled
>   rdmsr: 0xc0010112 Mar 28 00:17:43 vhost-server kernel: [  164.335752]
>   kvm: 3342: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010048 Mar 28 00:17:43
>   vhost-server kernel: [  164.502836] kvm: 3342: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr:
>   0xc0010001 Mar 28 00:17:44 vhost-server kernel: [  165.198538] kvm:
>   3392: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010112 Mar 28 00:17:44 vhost-server
>   kernel: [  165.198545] kvm: 3392: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010048 Mar
>   28 00:17:44 vhost-server kernel: [  165.364203] kvm: 3392: cpu0
>   unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010001 Mar 28 00:17:53 vhost-server kernel: [ 
>   174.093009] kvm: 3731: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010112

Things seem to be running fine.  Anyone have any idea what this is?

Comment: It sounds like this may be an already reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu-kvm/+bug/957957 You may want to take a look at that and indicate that you are also affected.

Answer (score 2):

[Not a bug:](http://my.oschina.net/anglix/blog/504822)
echo 1 > /sys/module/kvm/parameters/ignore_msrs

Comment: You really should have linked an english-speaking site. Most people in the world have no clue what is written there, and google translate is just 'not there', too.

Comment: didn't stop them...

Comment: Might be harmless http://askubuntu.com/questions/274326/kvm-error-in-syslog-says-cpu0-unhandled-rdmsr